# import data from one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I need to import all data from Server/Instance "Server Foo", Database "Foo" and table "Foo", into destination Server/Instance "Server Goo", Database "Goo" and table "Goo". Table Foo and Table Goo are of the same schema. If the same row exists for table Goo, I want to keep the origin data in Goo and ingore the import row in Foo (table Foo and table Goo both has a uniqueidentifier type column called CustomerID which acts as primary key and clustered index), just like ignore duplicate key does.

I am looking for simple and reliable ways to write T-SQL to solve data export/import issue. Any reference samples?

EDIT 1:

I have tried the below solution using MERGE, but met with the following error from SQL Server Management Studio. Any ideas what is wrong?

Some more information:

LabTest1\SQLServer2008 => Server\Instance name;
OrderDB => DB name;
dbo => schema name;
Orders => Table name.

```
merge into [dbo].[Orders] as Target
using "LabTest1\SQLServer2008.OrderDB.dbo.Orders" as source
on target.Hash = source.Hash
when not matched then
INSERT     ([Hash]
           ,[Order]
           ,[Name]
           ,[CreationTime]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES
     (
     source.[Hash], source.[Order], source.[Name], source.[CreationTime], source.[Description]
     )
when MATCHED then
;
```

Error message:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Then just delete out the WHEN MATCHED THEN line alltogether - you're not doing anything if the source and target entries match, right? You could issue an UPDATE statement here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you could script out your Goo.Goo table in SQL Server Mgmt studio and tell it to also create a script to insert all data by using T-SQL `INSERT` statements. Go the the Object Explorer, right-click on the database, pick "Tasks > Generate Scripts", pick the table you want to generate the data insert statements for, and make sure to use this option here:

[image]

Those could then be run on the other server to insert the table contents. In this case, however, you'd have to handle inserting possible existing rows yourself.

On the other hand, if both servers are on the same network, you could just use the "Linked Server" feature and link the source server to the target server and then use the SQL Server 2008 MERGE statement to import all the data from the source srever's table into the target server.

In the Object Explorer, go to "Server Objects", then "Linked Servers", right-click and "Add new linked server" to establish a connection between the two servers:

[image]

Once the servers are linked, a simple MERGE statement (new in SQL Server 2008) will allow you to merge the data from those two tables:

```
MERGE 
  INTO Goo.Goo as Target
  USING Foo.Foo.dbo.Foo as Source
  ON Source.ID = Target.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (field1, field2, field3)
  VALUES (source.field1, source.field2, source.field3)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  -- do nothing
;
```

Read more about the new MERGE statement here:

- http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Using-SQL-Server-2008-s-MERGE-statement/0,339028455,339283059,00.htm
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/3122/

or in the SQL Server 2008 Books Online.

Marc

Comment: Thanks Marc, for the linked server, how could I fill the "Linked Server" value in the New Linked Server wizard? I tried to input machine name but failed.

Comment: Did you pick the "SQL Server" option on the "New Linked Server / General" page? Just enter the name of the SQL Server instance you want to link to. On the other pages of the wizard, you might also need to specify credentials to connect to that server instance

Comment: Thanks Marc, if my source server name is foo, and instance name is fooinstance, I should enter foo\fooinstance? What is your recommended setting for credential?

Comment: Yes, enter "foo\fooinstance" - that should work. As for credentials - that's totally up to you. Either use an existing account you already have (e.g. one that the app connects to the database with), or create a specific one - whatever works for you

Comment: Thanks Marc, connection success. But failed to execute your merge statements, after "WHEN MATCHED THEN", it says syntax near ';' is wrong. I have posted my current TSQL and related error into EDIT1 section of my original post, any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Then just delete out the WHEN MATCHED THEN line alltogether - you're not doing anything if the source and target entries match, right? You could issue an UPDATE statement here

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Enterprise edition of SQL Server then why make your project difficult for yourself by using raw T-SQL code?

You can achieve your objectives in a more simple and robust manner by using [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (SSIS), a technology specifically designed to perform ETL tasks and is of course included with your edition of SQL Server.

Pre-built components already exist to process data in the manner which you desire and you have the added bonus of being able to easily incorporate auditing and logging capabilities into your solution.

What you are looking to achieve could be accomplished via pure T-SQL coding, however you would be making life more difficult for yourself in the process and the resulting solution would, in my opinion, most likely be cumbersome and less elegant.

Comment: Hi John, the SSIS URL cannot be opened. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me when I had a similar problem, I just copied the data from the SQL Server Management Studio output window and pasted it into an Excel file, then imported the data into the other database using this tool:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Excel2Sql.aspx