# How to transfer data from one table to another

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables,  I want to transfer all data from the first table to the second table in case of this data is not exits i nthe second table. how to do it using MS-sql server query ?

Comment: are they existing on only 1 database?

Comment: look also at first related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231748/import-data-from-one-table-to-another-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be something like:

```
INSERT INTO tableB(FieldA, FieldB, FieldC)
SELECT a.FieldA, a.FieldB, a.FieldC
FROM tableA a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM tableB b

    /* Primary key field(s)*/
    WHERE b.FieldA =a.FieldA 
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

in ms-sql you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(column1, column2) select value1, value2 from mytable2;
```

but you must make sure that the column1 and value1 have the same datatype same with column2.

Hope it helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the table doesn't exixst you can

```
SELECT * INTO SECOND_TABLE
FROM FIRST_TABLE;
```

If you want it to run even if table exists you can preceed this query with:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[YOUR_SCHEMA].[SECOND_TABLE]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [YOUR_SCHEMA].[SECOND_TABLE];
```